# Cannot access Sharepoint web part pages from client machines using SOAP connection - (401) Unauthorized error

Tags: web-part, web-services, soap, load-balancing

I desperately need some help on this guys, We have a 'Pages' library where we have saved all our custom web part pages.

Now, these pages (aspx) when invoked, connect to a web service that has some query stored and retrieve results from the external database. We have setup a Service in IIS for doing this, and everything works from the web front end servers.

But when trying to access the same from users machines, it gives out the error

> "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator."

Now, looking into the ULS logs, i could see the folowing error as well,

> "Error while executing web part: System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.      at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SoapDataSource.GetResponseString(SoapCommand
>   currentSoapCommand)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SoapDataSource.ExecuteInternal(SoapCommand
>   currentSoapCommand)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseXmlDataSource.Execute(String
>   request)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseXmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String
>   viewPath)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)"

I have looked for some solutions like putting the host file entries to point to the server itself. But nothing seems to work.

Could anyone please help, would really appreciate

Comment: Off the top of my head, smells like a double hop issue. Is your web service located on a different domain than your SharePoint aspx pages? If they are different (e.g. pages are at http://sharepoint.xyz and web service is at http://somethingelse.xyz) then your only option would be to move/install the web service in the same domain as SharePoint

Comment: Thanks Jared, I have set the kerberos authentication properly, as i checked and verified it.
Now, both the web service and sharepoint pages are located in the same domain, but yes they are having different host header names eg: example.domain.com and example-svc.domain.com Now, this actually works in dev, but only happens when I have 2 WFE servers. Everything works from the local WFE servers though. I have only set the windows authentication enabled, rest of them are disabled. Also, verfied my loopback check is disabled. pls let me know if you got any other ideas mate..